# Are there words meaning “helping somebody to think different/freely/more widely”?

Tags: single-word-requests

This is what my uncle does to me. I want write him a letter in English.

Comment: I have no idea what is being asked here. Please clarify.

Comment: In my native language, it's very clear. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Your uncle *broadened your horizons*.  Meaning he expanded your domain of thinking, opening you up to new ideas.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/broaden-one's-horizons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **maieutic** (adjective)
>
> of or denoting the Socratic mode of inquiry, which aims to bring a person's latent ideas into clear consciousness.

Comment: Also, the related noun for the method is **maieutics**.

Comment: This word is overly obscure. I don't think that the OP wants a word that 99% of all speakers have never heard of.

Answer (score 3):

You could say that your uncle has really **opened your mind**—introduced you to new things, changed the way you think about things, and made you more interested in considering other possible viewpoints.

Comment: Yes! this is really what I feel. He opened my mind! thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think **inspired** would be appropriate.

The word [inspire](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inspire) means to guide, influence and motivate and may capture the essence of what you're trying to say.